# active directory multiple managers/departments

Tags: active-directory

Is there any way to have multiple managers and/or departments in active directory?

Answer (score 4):

No, I'm afraid that's not possible. According to the standard Active Directory schema, the "manager" property of a user is a single-valued property, e.g. it can contain only a single value (or none).

Check out [Richard Mueller's site](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) with lots of great overviews of all AD attributes and more - excellent resource for AD related questions.

You could potentially extend the AD schema - that's always possible in LDAP - but it's not a very simple and awfully easy to understand process, I'm afraid......

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can create OU's in Active Directory, here is an example...

http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/setting-up-organizational-units-in-active-directory/

Comment: and a user can be part of multiple OUs?

Comment: No - a user object is contained in exactly one OU

Comment: A user can be member of any number of groups, however.

Answer (score -1):

Active directory is Microsofts implementation of the LDAP standard.  It conforms to the LDAP v3 standard.

So, yes, there is a way.

Comment: How can I do it?  Looking at the Manager and departement attribute, they are single value.

Comment: You assign the necessary people to groups and OUs.  Then specify permissions to those groups and OUs.

Comment: I can see how that might accomodate departments, what about managers?